# ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection refused

Tags: ssh, connection, git, github

So I followed the [guide on how to add a SSH key to GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/), and added a new SSH key with a passphrase to GitHub and the SSH agent. Now, if I run `ssh -T git@github.com` as described in the guide to test if I set everything up correctly, it doesn't even prompt me for my passphrase, but immediately returns `ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection refused`. I have both `openssh-server` and `openssh-client` installed and the SSH service is running.

[image: the error]

Help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: When I try and clone a repository which for which I have write access from a friend's GitLab instance, it throws the same error. Seems like this is a problem with SSH, not with the keys. (I have them added to the instance.)

Comment: You can't use `ssh -T git@github.com`. GitHub does not provide shell access.

Comment: @A.B. [it should at least return something though, shouldn't it?](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/#step-5-test-the-connection)

Comment: Yes, that's right: `% ssh -T git@github.com
Hi <you_username>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

Comment: For this reason, you should rephrase your question.

Comment: Check output of ssh -Tv git@github.com

Comment: This post is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953806/github-ssh-via-public-wifi-port-22-blocked

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589682/ssh-connect-to-host-github-com-port-22-connection-timed-out here configuring to port 443 worked for me.

Comment: A related but slightly off-topic answer if you are using cPanel. Run `ssh -Tv git@github.com`, add the remote IP address that is shown (for me 140.82.121.4) to SSH Authorisation on port 22 and you should be able to use port 22 and not switch to 443.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you get a connection refused, it means you actually got a packet back which states that your destination does not accept your connection.
This could mean a few things:

1. github.com is down (not too likely, but you could always check their status on https://status.github.com/)
2. you have an invalid IP address for github.com (manual entry in /etc/hosts or your resolver) which blocks ssh from at least your IP address
3. you have a firewall along the way to github.com which blocks the ssh traffic (eg. local firewall or corporate firewall)

Answer (score 43):

Have you tried using port 443, and adding `ssh.` subdomain prefix?

This command will test it.  You should get an error since a shell is not supported.

```
ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
```

Then you can use a full URL to specify the project path, see [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34444860/994153) for details:

```
ssh://git@ssh.github.com:443/yourname/reponame.git
```

---

Recommended `~/.ssh/config` setup as suggested in the comments:

```
# GitHub Account
Host github.com
HostName ssh.github.com
Port 443
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile <path to your private ssh key>
```

Comment: This helps to confirm that at least the connection to github can be made.

`$ ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
The authenticity of host '[ssh.github.com]:443 ([192.30.253.123]:443)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[ssh.github.com]:443,[192.30.253.123]:443' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Hi xcaliber! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

Comment: Thank you!  
This worked for me and made me realize that I also had to add this to my ssh config file    
  
`# GitHub Account Host  
github.com  
HostName **ssh.github.com**  
Port **443**  
PreferredAuthentications publickey  
IdentityFile <path to your private ssh key>`    
  
*note the HostName and Port

Comment: ta behind corporate firewall this helped alot